# Stormpath ruby sdk no method 'applications'

Tags: ruby, stormpath

I've been trying to test out the [stormpath ruby sdk](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-ruby). The instructions from the repo has been followed as is (copied here for clarity)

1. `require 'stormpath-sdk'`
2. `client = Stormpath::Client::Client.new({api_key: {id: "...", secret: "..."}})` (Note the addition of an extra `Client`, differs from documentation - cannot instantiate a module)

At this point, any further execution of commands as documented in the repo becomes impossible due to `undefined method` errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Stormpack::Client` [is a class](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-ruby/blob/master/lib/stormpath-sdk/client.rb#L19).
2. `Stormpack::Client.new` [is perfectly valid](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-ruby/blob/master/spec/client_spec.rb#L25).

You have a glitch somewhere else. Try to run and then copy their tests to get it working.

Comment: My bundler was targeting an extremely old version for some reason